This is a question about tkinter's <Configure> binding
I am a Windows 11 user. I wrote this code with the idea of ​​a canvas that changes size responsively when the window size changes.
However, when the program started, the window and canvas kept growing together.
I think it's because of some relationship between tkinter's window creation process and , but I'm curious as to why this phenomenon occurs.
import tkinter as tk

class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="red")
        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        # self.geometry("600x400")
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.config_canvas_size)

    def config_canvas_size(self, event=None):
        self.canvas.config(width=self.winfo_width(), height=self.winfo_height())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = app()
    root.mainloop()

If you have self.geometry("600x400") commented out, it will work as desired.
But that's what happens when there isn't one.

Since by default highlightthickness is 2 for Canvas widget, so the actual size occupied by a canvas may be bigger than the configured size.  So the window will be expanded which triggers the <Configure> event again.  Setting highlightthickness=0 when creating the canvas may fix the issue.  Actually you don't need to resize the canvas inside the callback because you have set fill=tk.BOTH and expand=True in self.canvas.pack(...).

This code seems to do what you want (Canvas change size responsively with the window size)
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg="red")
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

window.mainloop()

